# How to ensure timeout exception is thrown in HTTPS request

Tags: python, python-2.7, https

The timeout subject has been covered many times for HTTP, but I'm trying to test a HTTPS connection through a proxy.

urllib2, mechanize, httplib, requests are just some of the libraries that are reported to have issues with HTTPS timeouts.

I've also tried the popular: `socket.setdefaulttimeout(3)` and it still hung without timing out.

Does anyone have a method to test an HTTPS proxy on a HTTPS website with timeout working?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your request in dedicate thread or process and check request result periodically.
Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/14924210/853876

Comment: There surely must be another way? I can't believe there isn't a library for HTTPS requests through proxies with timeout support.